# Extract the textContent of an element using hyperscript

Tags: django, hyperscript

I have 2 elements in the DOM

```
<div 
   id="info_globals" style="display: none;" 
   hx-trigger="htmx_post_validation_trigger from:body" 
   hx-target="#info_globals" 
   hx-get="<snip>" 
   hx-include="[name='original_trigger_fld']" 
   hx-swap="innerHTML" 
   class=""
>
    <script id="info-length-lower" type="application/json">6</script>
    <script id="info-length-upper" type="application/json">6</script>
</div>
```

And I need to get these in some hyperscript on one of the form fields, but nothing seems to give me a value. I've tried several variations:

The post validation trigger is issued by some inline validation on the form triggered via htmx. This works OK. The update of these values also works OK.

The url for this calls an endpoint that is a django `TemplateView`, and the `get` method is overridden as follows.

```
    def get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: str, **kwargs: Any) -> HttpResponse:
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response["HX-Trigger"] = "htmx_post_globals_updated"
        return response
```

This is what I've thought would work, but neither seems to be.

```
set lowerBound to the textContent of #info-length-lower
set lowerBound to #info-length-lower.textContent
```

... and a few others along the way that I've forgotten now.

If I log this info out

```
log "globals updated"
set lowerBound to #info-length-lower.textContent
set upperBound to #info-length-upper.textContent
log "lower:", lowerBound, "upper:", upperBound
```

The console output is

```
globals updated
lower: "" upper: ""
```

How can I get this information out using hyperscript?

Comment: The second example should work fine, maybe you're missing something else. Can you show us how you execute the whole HS script, what event are you using etc?

Comment: It's a custom event that is emitted I'll try and add the flow.

Comment: OK, I've filled this out a bit. I'd tried to cut it down to the essentials for simplicity, but maybe the issue is hiding elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm wondering if the trigger comes and the hs runs before the hx-swap has occurred? I think it may not be gettnig the new values (and the old ones are initially empty, because the field that controls them isn't set yet).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so yes, @mariodev, `set lowerBound to #info-length-lower.textContent` should work, and in fact does.

The issue was to do with the fact that the trigger was running before the new values had been swapped into the HTML.

Changing the `HX-Trigger` to `HX-Trigger-After-Swap` solved this problem and allowed things to run in the correct sequence.

The reason it looked like it was the `set` not picking up values, is because initial values are empty (there's nothing to base them on yet, because the deciding field is also empty) so the process was going:

1. Trigger runs the hs `set` statements on existing empty values
2. `hx-swap` goes through
3. Values are now correct (when you look!) but too late!

Changing the trigger meant that the flow became:

1. `hx-swap` goes through
2. Values are now correct
3. Trigger runs the hs `set` statements